# Show independence of terms.

Tags: linear-algebra, independence

Let V be a 2 dimensional vector space. Show that the space of 3-linear symmetric forms on V is 4-dimensional?

I found the basis to be $$ACEw(x,x,x)+(ACF+ADE+BCE)w(x,x,y)+(ADF+BCF+BDE)w(x,y,y)+BDFw(y,y,y)$$ and I need to show that these terms are independent but I am stuck... Thanks. I know the basic ideas of independence but I am having trouble in this situation.

Comment: You have not yet described a basis but you have shown that a symmetric trilinear form $w$ is uniquely determined by the four numbers $w(x,x,x)$, $w(x,x,y)$, $w(x,y,y)$ and $w(y,y,y)$. Now try to convert this information into a description of a candidate for a basis cosisting of four trilinear symmetric forms. Having these forms at hand, think about linear independence again.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have been thinking about this a lot and I can't get it... :/

Comment: I probably need alphas and set it equal to zero to show all alphas are 0. But I can't figure out the set up.

Comment: Up to now, all you have done concerned a given trilinear symmetric form $w$. What you have to do is define 4 such forms, say $w_1,w_2,w_3,w_4$ appropriately. It is only than that you can start thinking about what it means that these 4 forms are linearly independent and span the space of all trilinear symmetric forms. It is certainly better if you try doing this yourself, but if you cannot figure it out tell me, I'll post an answer.

Comment: I think I got it. Thanks so much. :D